# Empty array with twitter rest get user_timeline

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to play with the twitter API. I did the oauth process, but when trying to get the user_timeline I get an empty array (but no authentication error, the http response is 200).
Any reason why this can happen?

this is the http response I get (I removed all oauth data...)

```
{'status': '200', 'x-ratelimit-remaining': '337', 'content-location': u'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?oauth_body_hash=....', 'x-transaction': '346e76fdbb36e2d8', 'set-cookie': 'guest_id="v1:134652550000237401"; Expires=Mon, 1-Sep-2014 18:51:40 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com, lang=en', 'expires': 'Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT', 'x-access-level': 'read-write', 'content-length': '2', 'server': 'tfe', 'last-modified': 'Sat, 01 Sep 2012 18:51:40 GMT', 'x-ratelimit-limit': '350', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0', 'date': 'Sat, 01 Sep 2012 18:51:40 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'x-ratelimit-class': 'api_identified', 'x-ratelimit-reset': '1346526376'}
```

but the content is just an empty array (in json format)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this was dumb issue. the issue was that the user has no tweets, so this was empty. Hope no one spent time on this.